# CAIRO_OPERATOR_CLEAR not working as expected

Tags: c++, cairo

I want to remove parts of a previously filled shape with Cairo and C++.

Consider the following MWE:

```
void test(cairo_t *cr){
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_paint(cr); //background

    cairo_rectangle(cr, 50, 50, 150, 150);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1);
    cairo_fill(cr); //first rect
    cairo_set_operator(cr,CAIRO_OPERATOR_CLEAR);
    cairo_arc(cr, 100, 100, 100, 0, M_PI * 2);
    cairo_fill(cr); //circle that show remove a part of the rect
}
```

It results in the following picture:

[image]

According to the [documentation](http://cairographics.org/operators/#clear) I would have expected no black color at all, and all parts of the blue rectangle, that are under the circle to become removed (and therefore white as the background).

Did I misunderstand the operator? Did I make any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would cairo know what you consider the background?

The documentation that you link to mentions that the alpha channels and all color channels are set to 0. This is fully transparent black.

The example in the documentation is an image with an alpha channel and thus the cleared parts become transparent.

You are using an image without an alpha channel and thus the cleared parts become black.

Comment: ok, thanks! Can you give me a short example how my code code be altered to get the desired result? (I want to remove a certain part of an object and replace the removed part with the background, which could be either a solid color or any pattern)

Comment: Draw the background again in that part with cairo_set_source_rgb() / cairo_set_source() and cairo_fill()?

Comment: Alternatively, use cairo_push_group() / cairo_pop_group_to_source() to draw your content to a temporary surface and then only draw the parts of it that you actually want to the target surface?